# Python: How do I get the IP address from a FQDN

Tags: python, network-programming, ip-address

If I have an FQDN e.g., www.google.com, how do I get the corresponding IP address?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is [`socket.gethostbyname()`](http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html#socket.gethostbyname).

Answer (score 6):

You can use `socket.getaddrinfo`. That will give you the differents IP address associated with the name, and can also give you the IPv6 address.

From the documentation:

```
>>> import socket
>>> help(socket.getaddrinfo)
Help on built-in function getaddrinfo in module _socket:

getaddrinfo(...)
    getaddrinfo(host, port [, family, socktype, proto, flags])
        -> list of (family, socktype, proto, canonname, sockaddr)

    Resolve host and port into addrinfo struct.
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(socket.getaddrinfo('www.google.com', 80))
[(2, 1, 6, '', ('74.125.230.83', 80)),
 (2, 2, 17, '', ('74.125.230.83', 80)),
 (2, 3, 0, '', ('74.125.230.83', 80)),
 (2, 1, 6, '', ('74.125.230.80', 80)),
 (2, 2, 17, '', ('74.125.230.80', 80)),
 (2, 3, 0, '', ('74.125.230.80', 80)),
 (2, 1, 6, '', ('74.125.230.81', 80)),
 (2, 2, 17, '', ('74.125.230.81', 80)),
 (2, 3, 0, '', ('74.125.230.81', 80)),
 (2, 1, 6, '', ('74.125.230.84', 80)),
 (2, 2, 17, '', ('74.125.230.84', 80)),
 (2, 3, 0, '', ('74.125.230.84', 80)),
 (2, 1, 6, '', ('74.125.230.82', 80)),
 (2, 2, 17, '', ('74.125.230.82', 80)),
 (2, 3, 0, '', ('74.125.230.82', 80))]
```

Note: `gethostbyname` is deprecated in C (and Python `socket.gethostbyname` is implemented with it) as it does not support IPv6 addresses, and `getaddrinfo` is the recommended replacement.

Answer (score 0):

Use `socket.gethostbyname(hostname)` see: http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html#socket.gethostbyname